# XQuery/XPath uses sql parameter?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, xquery

I am try to implement the following code.

```
declare @para varchar(10) = 'b';
declare @x xml = '
<x>
    <a>1111</a>
    <b>2222</b>
    <c>3333</c>
</x>';
select @x.query('/x/sql:variable("@para")');
```

The above code should get the node of `<b>2222</b>`. However, it get the following error

```
Msg 9335, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
XQuery [query()]: The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.
```

Comment: Not familial with XQuery in sql-server, but couldn't help wondering: wouldn't `query(concat('/x/', @para))` work?

Comment: @grtjn, the right syntax for query in SQL server is `@x.query('concat("/x/", sql:variable("@para"))')`. However it will return the string of `/x/b`only.

Comment: Thnx, learned something new..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
declare @para varchar(10) = 'b';
declare @x xml = '
<x>
    <a>1111</a>
    <b>2222</b>
    <c>3333</c>
</x>';
select @x.query('/x/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@para")]');
```